# Changing localStorage with <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append, local-storage

I am making a forum with an admin panel, where the admin can change the information users provide.

I am retrieving the user from localStorage to an `<input type="text">`, but I am not able to change the information and save it in the localStorage.

I get the erorr `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined` every time I click the edit button.

P.S: School project.

```
function seeUser(){
    $(document).on('click', ".user .glyphicon-edit", function() {
        var dataPage = "PersonalProfile";
        var personalProfileDiv = $("#personalProfile");
        $(".MyPage").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#personalProfile").html("");

        personalProfileDiv.append("<input type='text' id='userName' value='"+arrayUsers[$(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userId")].firstName+"'>");
        personalProfileDiv.append("<input type='text' id='userLastname' value='"+arrayUsers[$(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userId")].lastName+"'>");
        personalProfileDiv.append("<input type='text' id='userE-mail' value='"+arrayUsers[$(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userId")].email+"'>");
        personalProfileDiv.append("<input type='text' id='userPassword' value='"+arrayUsers[$(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userId")].password+"'>");
        personalProfileDiv.append("<button class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-userId='"+loggedInUserId+"' id='editUserBtn'>Edit user</button>");
    });
}

$(document).on('click', "#editUserBtn", function() {
    var userId = $(this).attr("data-userId");
    var userFirstNameChange = $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().val();
    var userLastNameChange = $(this).prev().prev().prev().val();
    var userEmailChange = $(this).prev().prev().val();
    var userPasswordChange = $(this).prev().val();
    arrayUsers[userId].firstName = userFirstNameChange;
    arrayUsers[userId].lastName = userLastNameChange;
    arrayUsers[userId].email = userEmailChange;
    arrayUsers[userId].password = userPasswordChange;
    localStorage.users = JSON.stringify(arrayUsers);
});
```

Comment: Your arrayUsers[userId] must be undefined for what ever reason. Where does this get set??

Comment: _Please_ cache `$(this)` and `$(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userId")`. Looking up those variables each time is inefficient. Caching those will also make your code shorter.

Comment: After you set userId try: console.log(userId). Is it defined? If so, console.log(arrayUsers). Is that defined as well? Also try inspecting the DOM after seeUser() runs. Is the HTML being created as you expected? Anything missing?

Comment: when i console.log the (userId) it gives me "[object Object]" I only have one user atm.

Console.log(arrayUsers) gives me the an object contaning the user:
0: Object 
email: "Bill@g.com"
firstName: "Bill"
lastName: "Henderson "
password: "123456"
role: "user"

The HTML is being created just as planned.